# Programmatically bind custom events for dynamic components in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In my vuejs app I use dynamic component in the following way:

```
<mycomponent>
  <component ref="compRef" :is="myComponent" v-bind="myComponentProps"></component>
  <div class="my-buttons">        
    <my-button label="Reset" @click="reset()"/>
  </div>
</mycomponent >
```

`myComponent` is a prop on the parent component which hold the actual component to inject.
`myComponentProps` are also prop which holds the porps for the injected instance.

I would like to know how can I also dynamically bind listeners to the component - I have understand that [I cannot](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5578) send an object to v-on with multiple events.

I was thinking about adding it programatically however haven't found any info about how it can be done for Vue custom events (kind for `addEventListener` equivalent for custom events)

Any tip would be much appreciated!

Comment: You *can* attach multiple handlers to events with an object as of Vue 2.4+ (see the last comment in the thread you linked). https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on

Answer (score 81):

With Vue 2.2+, you can programmatically add an event listener with [`$on(eventName, callback)`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created() {
    const EVENTS = [
      {name: 'my-event1', callback: () => console.log('event1')},
      {name: 'my-event2', callback: () => console.log('event2')},
      {name: 'my-event3', callback: () => console.log('event3')}
    ]

    for (let e of EVENTS) {
      this.$on(e.name, e.callback); // Add event listeners
    }

    // You can also bind multiple events to one callback
    this.$on(['click', 'keyup'], e => { console.log('event', e) })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.8/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <!-- v-on:EVENTNAME adds a listener for the event -->
    <button v-on:click="$emit('my-event1')">Raise event1</button>
    <button v-on:click="$emit('my-event2')">Raise event2</button>
    <button v-on:click="$emit('my-event3')">Raise event3</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- v-on shorthand: @EVENTNAME -->
    <button @click="$emit('my-event1')">Raise event1</button>
    <button @click="$emit('my-event2')">Raise event2</button>
    <button @click="$emit('my-event3')">Raise event3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

With Vue 2.6+, you can [add an event listener dynamically](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Dynamic-Arguments) in the template:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    eventname: 'click',
  },
  methods: {
    handler(e) {
      console.log('click', e.target.innerText)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.8/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @[eventname]="handler">Raise dynamic event</button>

  <!-- Set dynamic key to null to remove event listener -->
  <button @click="eventname = null">Unbind event</button>
</div>
```

You can also declaratively bind multiple event listeners with `v-on="{event1: callback, event2: callback, ...}"`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    onClick() { console.log('click') },
    onKeyUp(e) { console.log('keyup', e.keyCode) }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.8/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" placeholder="type here" v-on="{click: onClick, keyup: onKeyUp}">
</div>
```