# Pass events easily from a child component to a parent in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a base component `BaseInput.vue` which accepts attributes and emits events. It's easy to bind all attributes by using `v-bind="$attrs"` instruction.

```
// BaseInput.vue
<template>
  <label>
    <input
      v-bind="$attrs"
      @focus="$emit('focus')"
      @blur="$emit('blur')"
    >
  </label>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
};
</script>
```

Next I have a wrapper component `WrapInput.vue` which passes attributes to `BasicInput` and emits events.

```
// WrapInput.vue
<template>
  <basic-input
    v-bind="$attrs"
    @focus="$emit('focus')"
    @blur="$emit('blur')"
  />
</template>

<script>
import BasicInput from '@/storybook/pages/BasicInput';

export default {
  components: { BasicInput },
  inheritAttrs: false,
};
</script>
```

My question: is there a handy way in Vue to pass a bunch of events in "proxy" components without the need to list them one by one? I expect something like this:

```
// WrapInput.vue
<template>
  <basic-input
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-bind="$events" // is it possible to proxy all events in a single line?
  />
</template>

<script>
import BasicInput from '@/storybook/pages/BasicInput';

export default {
  components: { BasicInput },
  inheritAttrs: false,
};
</script>
```

P.S. I've heard about EventBus, but doesn't fit nicely for my case.

Comment: I think you have a same question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825246/bind-multiple-events-to-v-on-directive-in-vue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Vue 2, you could use [`v-on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) and [`$listeners`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners) to pass any event listeners to a component:

```html
// BasicInput.vue
<input v-on="$listeners">
```

[Vue 2 demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-all-event-handlers-e1gco?file=/src/components/BasicInput.vue:21-69)

In Vue 3, [`$listeners` is removed](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/listeners-removed.html), but any event listeners would be part of `$attrs`, so `v-bind="$attrs"` would suffice.

[Vue 3 demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-all-event-handlers-uizf3?file=/src/components/BasicInput.vue:21-51)

Answer (score -2):

Using Event Bus (Communication between any two components)
An event bus is used to communicate between any two components (Components need not have a parent-child relationship). This can be used when one needs to manually listen for events on a component instance.

You can just send the data from one component using `this.$root.$emit(’name-of-emitter’, args1, args2, ...)` and is captured using the same name like this `this.$root.$on(’name-of-emitter’, args1, args2, ...)` in the other component.

Source of the answer: https://dev.to/sanchithasr/how-to-communicate-between-components-in-vue-js-kjc