# Bind events with an object on VUE.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm new on vue.js and I searched on the docs and could not find if it is possible to bind the events with one single object. Can someone help me?

from:

```
<input @input="inputEvent" @selected="selectedEvent"/>
```

to:

```
theEvents =  {
   "input" : () => this.inputEvent(),
   "selected" : () => this.selectedEvent(),
}

<input v-bind:"theEvents" />
```

Comment: I think I'd start with `v-on="theEvents"` instead of `v-bind`. See the examples here ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on

Answer (score 2):

First of all it should be v-on and second of all you should directly put the method unless you are writing the callback function inside data,

```
<div id="mydDiv" v-on="handlers"></div>

// ...

data() {
  const vm = this;

  return {
    handlers: {
      mousedown: vm.divMousedown,
      touchstart: vm.divTouchstart
    }
  }
},

methods: {
  divMousedown() {
    console.log('event: mousedown');
  },
  divTouchstart() {
    console.log('event: touched');
  }
}

 const EVENTS = [
      {name: 'my-event1', callback: () => console.log('event1')},
      {name: 'my-event2', callback: () => console.log('event2')},
      {name: 'my-event3', callback: () => console.log('event3')}
    ]
```

copied from [Bind multiple events to v-on directive in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825246/bind-multiple-events-to-v-on-directive-in-vue/53825805)