# Programatically assign handler for native event in Vue JS?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to leverage a Vue mixin to add behavior when a native event happens. Using a mixin will allow me to share that across several components. Specifically, when a field component (or button, or checkbox, etc.) has focus, and the `Escape` key is pressed, the field loses focus.

A [similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250832/programmatically-bind-custom-events-for-dynamic-components-in-vuejs?rq=1#answer-48251122) seemed to indicate I could listen for native events (see code comment about multiple events).

However, the [Vue Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on) for programmatically adding an event listener using `$on` says that it will

> Listen for a *custom event* on the current vm...

(Emphasis added)

Unsure if the *custom event* remark is absolute or based on the context, I have been experimenting. I have been trying to listen for the native `keyup` event (using the Vue alias `keyup.esc`) but have had no success. So I am wondering if it is indeed limited to custom events, and if so, why?

You can see my experiment in a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-8r54l). The custom event works, the native does not.

The mixin looks like so:

```js
// escape.mixin.js
export default {
  created() {
    // Custom event
    this.$on("custom-event", function() {
      console.log("Custom event handled by mixin");
    });

    // Native event
    this.$on(["keyup.esc", "click"], function() {
      alert("Native event handled!");
    });
  }
};
```

The main point of all this is to be able to add the behavior to a set of components by adding to how the event is handled, without overriding behavior that might also exist on the component. The secondary goal is to provide the behavior by simply adding the mixin, and not having to do component level wiring of events.

So a component script would look something like this:

```js
// VText component
import escapeMixin from "./escape.mixin";

export default {
  name: "VText",
  mixins: [escapeMixin],
  methods: {
    onFocus() {
      console.log("Has Focus");
      this.$emit("custom-event");
    }
  }
};
```

Also, I was trying to avoid attaching the listener to the `<input>` element directly with vanilla JS because the Vue documentation suggested that letting Vue handle this was a good idea:

> [When using v-on...] When a ViewModel is destroyed, all event listeners are automatically removed. You don’t need to worry about cleaning it up yourself.

**Solution**

[skirtle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8583563/skirtle)'s solution in the comment below did the trick. You can [see it working in a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-4pz73).

Or here's the relevant mixin:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$el.addEventListener("keyup", escapeBlur);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.$el.removeEventListener("keyup", escapeBlur);
  }
};

function escapeBlur(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    e.target.blur();
    console.log("Lost focus");
  }
}
```

Comment: If by 'vanilla JS' you mean `this.$el.addEventListener(...)` in the `mounted` hook and `this.$el.removeEventListener(...)` in the `beforeDestroy` hook then I'd be inclined to go with that. Custom events and DOM events are totally different things behind the scenes and it's only the template syntax that makes them appear related. A custom directive might be a viable alternative to a mixin but the event registration problem is much the same.

Comment: Thanks @skirtle - I'll give that a try. Yes, that's what I meant by Vanilla JS - but I hadn't thought of using the `beforeDestroy` hook to manage the clean up. Good idea...

Comment: @skirtle - that worked beautifully! Thank you so much. It's slightly more code in the keyup listener, but it's all contained in one place so it's perfect. Awesome.