# Vue.js custom events from constants

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, constants

I have a Vue.js component that publishes certain events.

```
<MyComponent @some-event="myHandler"/>
```

Inside the component you have something like

```
this.$emit('some-event', someData);
```

Pretty basic. But to make the code cleaner, it would be nice if I could have a the string `'some-event'` defined in a constant somewhere and to be able to use it with `$emit()` and when declaring the the event handler. Something like this:

```
const EVENT_NAME = 'some-event';

this.emit(EVENT_NAME, someData);

<MyComponent @{{EVENT_NAME}}="myHandler"/>
```

I just made up the `@{{EVENT_NAME}}` syntax but hopefully the idea makes sense. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically bind custom events for dynamic components in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250832/programmatically-bind-custom-events-for-dynamic-components-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic Arguments](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Dynamic-Arguments), e.g. (being `event_name` the constant):

```
<MyComponent @[event_name]="myHandler" />
```

but with some caveats:

- There are [several constraints](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Dynamic-Argument-Expression-Constraints) to what you can use inside the `[]`;
- For the `event_name` constant to be used in the template, it **must be accessible to the template**, which means it should be a `data` property, a computed, or similar. It does not suffice to merely be declared in the script, outside of the vue component.
- Attributes will be parsed as lowercase, so your constant must be `event_name`, not `EVENT_NAME` or `Event_Name` (you can even use those, but they will be treated as `event_name`; see how I declare the `data` below).

Working demo:

```js
const EVENT_NAME = 'some-event';

Vue.component(`my-component`, {
  template: `
    <button @click="myCompInternalHandler">click me to emit an event whose name is the value of event_name</button>
  `,
  methods: {
    myCompInternalHandler() {
      this.$emit(EVENT_NAME, {someData: 112233});
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    event_name: EVENT_NAME // key has to be lowercase, because it is used in the template as dynamic attr
  },
  methods: {
    myHandler(e) {
      console.log('received at parent:', e);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component @[event_name]="myHandler" />
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Clever approach, but sort of nullifies the point of generating constants in the first place, since in `<my-component @[event_name]=`  the IDE (e.g. WebStorm) can't find the reference to `event_name`. Thus it appears the constant is no more useful than a string :-(