# Using custom events in a component that is registered programmatically [VUE]

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli-3

i am appending a child component in Vue programmatically as seen below:

```
var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(FormulaGeneratorConstant) //create instance from FormulaGeneratorConstant component

this.constants.push('variable1');

var constant = new ComponentClass({
    propsData: {
        value: this.constants[this.constants.length - 1]
    }
});

constant.$mount();

this.$refs.droppableContainer.$el.appendChild(constant.$el)
```

but right now i can only pass props in this code.

i would like to know how to implement v-model and handle custom events as well if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250832/programmatically-bind-custom-events-for-dynamic-components-in-vuejs).

i just passed a `created` function inside the `new Component` constructor:

```
var constant = new ComponentClass({
    propsData: {
        value: this.constants[this.constants.length - 1]
    },
    created(){
        this.$on(['change'], e => { console.log(e); })
    }
});
```