# How to dynamically assign keyboard events in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When I bind keydown event for `alt + 1` combination on the main component's element like so:

```html
<div
    @keydown.alt.49.prevent.exact="doSomething()"
>
```

It works, but when I try to bind it dynamically based on some logic in created (inspired by [Programmatically bind custom events for dynamic components in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250832/programmatically-bind-custom-events-for-dynamic-components-in-vuejs)):

```js
created() {
    this.$on('keydown.alt.49.prevent.exact', doSomething);
},
```

It does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument of [`vm.$on()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on) is the *event name*, but you've passed it the *event name along with the [event modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)*, which are only valid in the template.

```js
keydown                 // Event name
.alt.49.prevent.exact   // Event modifiers
```

An equivalent method that implements the event modifiers would look like this:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    eventHandler(e) {
      // .alt.49
      //   `keyCode` 49 is deprecated, so use `key` equivalent
      //   for Alt+1: the inverted exclamation point, not '1'
      const isAlt1 = e.altKey && e.key === '¡'

      // .exact
      const isExact = !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey

      if (isAlt1 && isExact) {
        // .prevent
        e.preventDefault()

        // this.doSomething()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To add that event handler to the `div`, apply a [template `ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref):

```html
<div ref="myEl"></div>
```

Then access the element via [`this.$refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs), and use the element's native [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
this.$refs.myEl.addEventListener('keydown', this.eventHandler)
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JjXpjXd?editors=1010)